# RaphaelJS : back and forth animation repeated

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I have a simple animation, made with **RaphaelJS** : **I just want a circle "blink" smoothly 4 times (animating opacity property)**.

In the end, this is what I've done :

```
circleBackground.animate({'opacity': 0.2}, duration/2/8, "easeIn", function() {
            circleBackground.animate({'opacity': 0}, duration/2/8, "easeOut", function() {
                circleBackground.animate({'opacity': 0.2}, duration/2/8, "easeIn", function() {
                    circleBackground.animate({'opacity': 0}, duration/2/8, "easeOut", function() {
                        circleBackground.animate({'opacity': 0.2}, duration/2/8, "easeIn", function() {
                            circleBackground.animate({'opacity': 0}, duration/2/8, "easeOut", function() {
                                circleBackground.animate({'opacity': 0.2}, duration/2/8, "easeIn", function() {
                                    circleBackground.animate({'opacity': 0}, duration/2/8, "easeOut", function() {

                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

But well, **this seems pretty dirty and I want to clean it up, to make a more readable / maintainable version of this**.

*I tried `.repeat()` but I'm only able to repeat the half of the animation (opacity from 0 to 0.2 repeated, not 0.2 to 0), and that doesn't give the effect I'm looking for.*

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this:

```
var paper = new Raphael("myDiv", 100, 100);
var rect = paper.rect(20,20,20,20).attr({fill: "red", opacity: 0});
var cmp = 3;

var anim = Raphael.animation({opacity: 0.2}, 500, "easeIn", function () {
    rect.animate({opacity: 0}, 500, "easeOut", function () {
        if (cmp > 0) {
            rect.animate(anim); cmp--;
        }
    });
});

rect.animate(anim);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Manegan/mfx76jem/1/

It kind of works... I don't know if this is the result you need.

Edit: The problem is that the animation repeats itself when it is done without waiting for the callback to complete... I'll try to find a solution.

Edit: Found something that works fine but a bit dirty. Still kinda "clean".

Comment: Yes, it's what I've done before, but as you said, it doesn't trigger the callback before repeating the animation :(

Comment: Yeah, I realised it. I've found a solution and edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the solution of Manegan and use the Raphael.animation function `.repeat()`. It looks like this now:

```
var paper = new Raphael("myDiv", 100, 100);
var rect = paper.rect(20,20,20,20).attr({fill: "red", opacity: 0});
var cmp = 3;
var animationTime = 500;

var anim = Raphael.animation({opacity: 0.2}, animationTime, "easeIn", function () {
    rect.animate({opacity: 0}, animationTime, "easeOut");
}).delay(animationTime).repeat(cmp);

rect.animate(anim);
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t33swt92/1/

You can find the documentation for `.repeat()`[here.](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Animation.repeat)

Comment: Thank you, but this is the same as @Manegan posted the first time (it doesn't trigger the callback before repeating the animation). Manegan updated answer is the render I want.

Comment: It does. Did you take a look at the fiddle?! I included the necessary delay.

Comment: No it doesn't : on the 2 first loops, you can see it's animating to 0.2 opacity then (with no transition), it goes to 0 opacity. On the third loop, it works.

Comment: I mean, just compare @Manegan live demo and yours, not the same render (at least on my Chrome/Mac).